# making phpexcel directory save to download?

Tags: php, phpexcel

How can I make it possible for a user choose where to save the file like its kind of download you know, here is the code below:

```
echo date('H:i:s').' Set title row bold'.EOL;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:F1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

// Set autofilter
echo date('H:i:s').' Set autofilter'.EOL;
// Always include the complete filter range!
// Excel does support setting only the caption
// row, but that's not a best practise...
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()-           >calculateWorksheetDimension());

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel2007 format" , EOL;
$callStartTime = microtime(true);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__, 'C:/DOSTX.xlsx', __FILE__));

$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;

echo date('H:i:s') , " File written to " , str_replace('.php', '.xlsx',     pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) , EOL;
echo 'Call time to write Workbook was ' , sprintf('%.4f',$callTime) , " seconds" , EOL;

// Echo memory usage

echo date('H:i:s') , ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024)  , " MB" , EOL;

// Save Excel 95 file
echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel5 format" , EOL;
$callStartTime = microtime(true);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));
$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;
ECHO $filename= str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) ,     EOL;
echo date('H:i:s') , " File written to " , str_replace('.php', '.xls',    pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) , EOL;
echo 'Call time to write Workbook was ' , sprintf('%.4f',$callTime) , " seconds" , EOL;

// Echo memory usage

echo date('H:i:s') , ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024)  , " MB" , EOL;


// Echo memory peak usage

echo date('H:i:s').' Peak memory usage: '.(memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024).'   MB'.EOL;

// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s').' Done writing files'.EOL;

echo "<script>alert('File saved at drive C')</script>";
```

I've done many headings before but doesnt just work it does with phpoutput but excel is not acceptable output, excel file cannot be read as what I want it to be output please help me.

Comment: i am using excel 2007 anyway what headings should i use? examples on phpexcel works on its file but when i copy it for this it just dont work? im working by the way on 10autofilter.php

Comment: save locally or save on the server?

Comment: yes locally like when it executes the file is downloaded automatically? i use phpoutput before but excel not viewing correctly what heading to use? or how to use phpoutput correctly?

Comment: the user's browser determines the location, you have no control over that

Comment: yes they control but i mean that when this program run then download then they open and save it by user you know,so user download this, sorry bad english

Comment: this code from phpexcel is save to directory i want to make it save to download?

Answer (score 0):

now i get it

replace:

```
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));
```

with:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_name.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


// This line will force the file to download
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

you will have to remove all that output or the header calls will fail.

Comment: still not viewing correctly ive tried the codes on 01simple also :( to add there is this code below my query $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension());

Comment: what is the *specific* problem?

Comment: excel not viewing correctly but inputs are there just not proper but download is already ok